# c++ edit specific word from line in textfile

Tags: c++

I have a text file than contains the itemId , itemName, price

itemInfo.txt

```
1,samsung galaxy 4,1000
2,levis pants,100
3,jacket,100
```

what I want to do is if the user want to change the price of the jacket from 100 to 50, the program will detect the id of jacket(in this case is line 3) and change the price of it for jacket. or if the user wants to change 'levis pants' to 'tshirt' it will detect the id(in this case is line 2) and change the name of it.

I know how to read the file line by line. but I don't know any ideas what should I do after reading the file line by line and achieve the output that I wanted. Please advise. thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow! Here are a few pointers why you might not get the answers you are looking for with the way the question is currently written: It is not so clear what you actually want / what the program should really do. how should the program "detect" that the user is changing anything? where does the user do that change? Directly via the program? Does he edit the file? Also, if you expect somebody here to help you with code, it's usually best to show that you tried writing some yourself by showing the code snipped which causes problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is 2 ways in which you can do this:

1. Write over the current file with the new values, this means reading all data in, then writing back out in the same format, this is the easiest method, just use ofstream to write the same data out
2. Use a stream pointer in the ofstream library, check out [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) resource (hint: seekp, tellp and write), this will "move" to a point in the file and then write out directly from that point, this is a more complex but more efficient method.

Example of #1:

```
int rowCount = 0;
// read in file here and count the number of rows in the text file.

ofstream output;
output.open("itemInfo.txt", ofstream::out);

for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) // 
    output << itemId[i] << "," << itemName[i] << "," << price[i] << endl;
```

Example of #2:
    I cant be bothered